# Beautiful Soup unable to grab information from table

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

A few months into python, and am having trouble scraping some information from tables using BeautifulSoup, any help would be appreciated. I am not getting any error codes, but instead just receiving no data from the table.

```
import bs4 as bs
import requests

resp = requests.get('https://www.thestreet.com/markets/gainers.html')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "lxml")
table = soup.find('table', {'id': 'nyseData'})

tickers = []
for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
     ticker = row.findAll('td')[1].text
     tickers.append(ticker)
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running in to a problem with the page not allowing certain user-agents from accessing their site. This can be fixed by setting a user-agent string in your `requests` header.

Your code with the user-agent added:

```
import bs4 as bs
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36'}

resp = requests.get('https://www.thestreet.com/markets/gainers.html', headers=headers)
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text,'lxml')
table = soup.find('table', {'id': 'nyseData'})

tickers = []
for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
     ticker = row.findAll('td')[1].text
     tickers.append(ticker)

print tickers
```

Output:

```
[u'QUOT', u'BCEI', u'ATEN', u'SKX', u'FBK', u'FBM', u'CGI', u'SDRL', u'ELLI', u'CELP', u'SXCP', u'CUB', u'GLF', u'SID', u'HBM', u'NE', u'CBG', u'PJT', u'VVI', u'ARL']
```